# Sorting the sorted data in sql server

Tags: sql-server

The query inside `***` and `***` will produce the partitioned rows ordered by `status_date`. Now, if that result has more than one row with same  `status_date` then I want to sort only those row by `change_date`.

I have come up with the below query but it's not giving the desired result.

```
 SELECT  MID,status_date,status,change_date, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY MID ORDER BY  change_date DESC )  as RN1, 1 as TimeRange
                    FROM 
                        (
                    *** SELECT MID,status_date,status,change_date,
                        rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY MID ORDER BY status_date DESC)
                        FROM listing_History   (nolock)
                         WHERE  MID like  '12-572561'  ****

                        )  AS A
```

For Reference :

The results from  query inside `***` and `***` :

```
12-572561   2012-06-11 00:00:00.000 Canceled    2012-06-11 14:53:22.957  1
12-572561   2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 Canceled    2012-03-01 13:32:40.030  2
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-01-02 07:32:34.067  3
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-06-11 07:43:29.400  4
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-01-10 00:01:03.407  5
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-06-11 07:43:29.417  6
```

The results with the existing query :

```
12-572561   2012-06-11 00:00:00.000 Canceled    2012-06-11 14:53:22.957  1  1
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-06-11 07:43:29.417  2  1
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-06-11 07:43:29.400  3  1
12-572561   2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 Canceled    2012-03-01 13:32:40.030  4  1
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-01-10 00:01:03.407  5  1
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-01-02 07:32:34.067  6  1
```

Desired results :

```
12-572561   2012-06-11 00:00:00.000 Canceled    2012-06-11 14:53:22.957  1  1
12-572561   2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 Canceled    2012-03-01 13:32:40.030  2  1
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-06-11 07:43:29.417  6  1
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-06-11 07:43:29.400  4  1
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-01-10 00:01:03.407  5  1
12-572561   2012-01-02 00:00:00.000 Active      2012-01-02 07:32:34.067  3  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[ORDER BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)** for `change_date` at the end of the query

Answer (score 2):

The row_number() function doesn't determine order for the results.  You need an ORDER BY clause.  If you don't need the row_number() values in the results, you can do the following

```
SELECT MID,status_date,status,change_date
FROM listing_History   (nolock)
WHERE  MID like  '12-572561'
ORDER BY status_date DESC, change_date DESC
```

Comment: I get the following error : "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: Is your query part of a view, inline function, derived table, subquery or common table expression?  Or, are you trying to embed the change in your current query?

Comment: I had to put the Order by at the end of the query as LUV has mentioned.

Comment: Try running the query as shown to see if it gives you what you want.